# Network settings

Tags: linux, networking, settings

how can change my pc settings in linux so that my network cannot recognise my previous mac address and thinks that is a new pc that connects to network via wifi. I ask this because something went wrong and cannot connect because my pc is blocked from this network

Comment: This is off-topic! Ask on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your MAC address on Linux (or OSX), use the command ifconfig :

```
ifconfig [interface name] hw ether [new MAC address]
```

Example:
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06